# n-formula for k n-evaluations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

I am trying to solve the following problem

Let $N = \{0, 1, 2, ...\} $ is the set of natural numbers. Propositional variables are $ A_{n}$ for $n \in N $ . An evaluation  $v$ is  called $n$-evaluation, iff $v(A_{k})=0$ for each $k \geq n$ (there exist $2^{n}   $  n-evaluations  ). A formula is  called n-formula, iff it does not contain negation, conjuncion, disjunction (implication only); it does not contain variable $A_{k}$ for each $k \geq n$ too.

I am trying to find for which pairs $(n, k) \in N^{2}$ there exists an n-formula, which is true for exactly k n-evaluations.

I guess it is about class of boolean functions $O^{\infty}$ ($T_{1,\infty}$), which is a closure of the implication.